# How to stylize a pair of elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of divs, like this

```
<div class="row header"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<!-- add spacing here by adding margin to the row above -->
<div class="row header"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

As I cannot change markup, I wonder if I can add a space between `.row` and `.row.header` only without making any changes to other divs. Ideally, I need to add `margin-bottom` to every `.row` that is put before `.row.header`.

Is this possible with CSS at all without adding extra classes and hacks?

Comment: can't you add `margin-top` to `.row.header`?

Comment: @TomaszRup if all `.row.header` elements need such margins, then `margin-top` would suffice. The user specifically asks for "space between `.row` and `.row.header`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is indicated in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/2894798 there is no previous sibling selector in css, I would recommend to add margin top to .row.header

```
.row + .row.header{
margin-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
.row + .row.header {
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

This will only add a top margin to those `.row.header` elements which come after `.row` elements, making sure that the first `.row.header` element is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to add top margin to divs with both `row` and `header` classes

```
.row.header {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want apply margin only where is the comment is written you can add css for that as follows

div.row:nth-of-type(4) {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

but if you want add margin to every 3'd div after .header, you need to apply css as follows

div.row:nth-of-type(4n) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Hope this will full fill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `:not()` selector if `.row.header` is first child of it's parent. For [more info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```
.row.header:not(:first-child) { 
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```